# Maven Jackson Databind Update java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/JsonProcessingException

Tags: java, maven, jackson

I am working on a project that requires I update jackson-databind (so com.fasterxml.jackson.core) from 2.9.10.4 to 2.10.0 to get rid of some vulnerability issues that the current version exposes them to. Because of project requirements I can only upgrade to a lower required version so I'm starting at the lowest possible version to circumvent the vulnerabilities which is 2.10.0.

On my local the build passes, and it both builds and successfully deploys in Jenkins. However, when we bounce our Weblogic server we get this error that stems from a .war file. This error does not show up for the prior version, and does not show up before the  change. My thought is that class in question was part of the jackson core library that is being updated to get jackson databind updated removed the class entirely and I might have to use a new dependency to get it, but I can find no documentation that confirms that.

**Error log:**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/JsonProcessingException

    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)

    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)

 - List item

    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2020)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:231)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1004)

Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonProcessingException

    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1029)

    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:990)

    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:101)

    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:611)

    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:543)
```

---

**Jackson dependency:**

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
   <version>2.9.10.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Try to to perform a mvn dependency:tree (or equivalent if you use another build system) and see if some other dependency is transitively pulling the dependency that contains the JsonProcessingException. If that's the case, it is possible that it works locally because the class is in your repository, but it doesn't remotely because the class is not there any longer and if that's the case, you should simply exclude that transitive dependency to make your code use the explicit one.

Comment: It might be useful to see the a part of your pom.xml, so it is clear what jackson dependecy you use (and how).

Comment: I added the dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add `jackson-core` dependency to your **pom.xml**. It has the `org.codehaus.jackson.JsonProcessingException`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```